# Adding 'git help' for alias commands?

Tags: git, alias

I've implemented a Git command and used git aliases to hook it into Git but is there a way to hook the Git help?  I'm running on Windows and if I issue `git help mycmd` I get a popup telling me that Git can't find a git-mycmnd.html file.

I've implemented my command using Python so is there a proper Git-ish way to add the help in, other than 'just knowing' where help files have to be placed?

Comment: I just tested an alias `hello` which runs `git show HEAD` and when I run `git help hello` I get a response `'hello' is aliased to 'show HEAD'`

Comment: Check  `help.format` and `help.htmlpath` [Here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-helphtmlPath). `git config --local  help.htmlpath "http://www.google.com"` then `git help love` this should give you an idea about where to start

Comment: Here's hoping someone can help to work out how this would work in general, by modifying the files which are part of Git rather than having to manually keep a Git repo in sync with the currently installed Git version.

Answer (score 5):

You can have customised documentation for for your aliases, and the documentation can be either locally saved or online accessible over the web. Here's how it works:

#### First: set the help format

```
git config --local help.format html
```

#### Second: clone the official get documentation

```
cd ~/Documents

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-htmldocs.git git-doc
```

#### Third: add a simple HTML page that contains documentation for your command

Assuming your command is `love` so:

```
cd ~/Documents/git-doc
touch gitlove.html 
Add some text to the gitlove.html
```

#### Fourth: configure your repo to link to the documentation repo

```
cd YOUR_PROJECT_REPO
git config --local help.htmlpath ~/Documents/git-doc
```

Now you can do: `git help love` and your html page will pop up.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks William.  That's a lot of effort when aliasing the command is so easy :-(.

Comment: @PaulDSmith not so much work actually, you're basically cloning a repo and adding your HTML page there! Indeed even better if you have your HTML hosted somewhere, you'd need just to point to your domain, that's it!

Comment: for me, I agree.  But as a way to roll out a useful git extension to a lot of people, I can get away with 'pip install this then run this git alias command', but I can't ask people to start messing around with Git documentation like this.  My 'perfect' solution would be some sort of 'help alias', probably working off the alias, that perhaps passed 'help' and a format (man, html etc) and let me script do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

> hoping someone can help to work out how this would work in general, by modifying the files which are part of Git rather than having to manually keep a Git repo in sync with the currently installed Git version

[The method provided earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56636503/6309) requires cloning the official Git documentation repository and keeping it in sync manually, which could be cumbersome.

From what I understand:

- `git help love` → `man git-love`: displays the man page for git-love, if it exists: e.g., `/usr/local/share/man/man1/git-love.1`.
- `git love --help` → `git-love --help`: executes the `git-love` script with the `--help` flag

To get a more streamlined solution that integrates with the installed Git version directly, you might consider, instead of creating an alias:

- to create a script (e.g., `git-love`) and place it in a directory that is on your system's PATH.
  That script could be written in Python, as you have mentioned, you have implemented your command using Python.
- to create a man page for your `git-love` script. Name it `git-love.1` and place it in an appropriate directory where man pages are stored (e.g., `/usr/local/share/man/man1/`). The man page will allow the `git help love` command to bring up the help text for your script, since Git's help system uses man pages to display help text​.

```py
import argparse
import subprocess
import sys

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your git love command.', add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('--help', action='store_true', help='Show help message and exit')
    args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    if args.help:
        # Display the man page
        subprocess.run(['man', 'git-love'])
    else:
        # rest of your command implementation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That way, the `argparse.ArgumentParser` is created with `add_help=False` to prevent `argparse` from automatically handling the `--help` flag.
A custom `--help` argument is added to the parser. If `--help` is provided as an argument, the `subprocess.run` function is used to execute the `man git-love` command, displaying the `git-love.1` man page.
Otherwise, the rest of your command implementation would run.

Comment: Quite a neat idea.  I guess I could also add something that would open a local HTML file on Windows :-).